# Trying to get bash through docker exec, but nothing works (Jaeger container) --> OCI runtime exec failed

Tags: bash, shell, docker, jaeger

I've been trying to run basic shell commands, ls as an example, but any of them work.
So, I've tried to validate if the container has a bash enabled, and answers to similar posts say to run:

```
docker exec -it amazing_robinson //bin//bash
docker exec -it amazing_robinson /bin/bash
docker exec -it amazing_robinson //bin//sh
docker exec -it amazing_robinson /bin/sh
docker exec -it amazing_robinson sh
docker exec -it amazing_robinson bash
```

But any of them work (neither docker exec -it amazing_robinson ls).

This is the error:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/bash\": stat /bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

The container is

```
 jaegertracing/example-hotrod:latest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the your [base image](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/blob/master/examples/hotrod/Dockerfile) it from scratch.

```
FROM scratch
EXPOSE 8080 8081 8082 8083
COPY hotrod-linux /go/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/hotrod-linux"]
CMD ["all"]
```

So there is no **Bash, ash** as the image is from scratch so it will only cotnain `hotrod-linux`.

To get sh or bash in such cases you need to use multi-stage Dockerfile, you can use the base image in Dockerfile and then copy the binaries from the base image in multi-stage in Dockerfile. Here you go

```
FROM jaegertracing/example-hotrod:latest as base
FROM alpine
COPY --from=base /go/bin/hotrod-linux /go/bin/hotrod-linux
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/hotrod-linux"]
CMD ["all"]
```

so now you can build and test and you will able to run command inside container using docker exec, here is the example

```
docker build -t myimage .

docker run -dit --name test myimage

#now run
docker exec -it test ash
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FROM scratch
EXPOSE 8080 8081 8082 8083
COPY hotrod-linux /go/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/hotrod-linux"]
CMD ["all"]
```

https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/blob/master/examples/hotrod/Dockerfile

As I can see hotrod image was built from scratch image. And from the docker hub:

> "an explicitly empty image, especially for building images "FROM
>   scratch"...
>
> "This image is most useful in the context of building base images
>   (such as debian and busybox) or super minimal images (that contain
>   only a single binary and whatever it requires, such as hello-world)."

https://hub.docker.com/_/scratch

So, I think there is not bash inside this image